# Cannot call prototype function from outside

Tags: javascript

I have a Mapper function that I want to call its prototype function method which is `foo`. However for some reason it's not executing when I use `mapper.prototype.foo()`. Is there a way to call it outside of the function?

```js
function Mapper() {
  return (site) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("yes");
    });
}

Mapper.prototype.foo = function() {
  console.log("afsd");
};

const mapper = new Mapper();
mapper.prototype.foo();
mapper("google.com");
```

Comment: `Mapper` returns a function, so that's what will be set to `mapper`, not an instance.

Comment: It's `mapper.foo()` (if you used "proper" old school OO. we have `class` now though)

Comment: You are returning a new function from `Mapper` so it won't have that prototype at the end because you are get a `Function` and not a `Mapper`. Also, you'd call such a prototype method without `.prototype.`.

Comment: Here's what I meant: https://jsfiddle.net/72qdbsmn/

Comment: @Andy even without the promise, `Mapper` returns a function which also screws it up.

Comment: @evolutionxbox if function Mapper return itself (this), can the prototype foo be called outside?

Comment: Try it and see?

Comment: Normally the constructor function shouldn't return anything. `new` will then automatically return the `this` object that was passed to the constructor.

Comment: If you're adamant about that having that promise put it in its own prototype function and then call it: `mapper.init().then(...);`.